# how to implement a custom autocomplete text view android

Tags: android, autocomplete, textview

I want to implement the autocomplete text view but with my own rules and limits

for example if I typed : "allo" and the the adapter has : "akkgg", "gggallop", "aaaa"
the result will be "gggallop"

thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can check the Apidemos AutoComplete4 example. It has a custom filtering. You will have to use runQueryOnBackgroundThread of the adapter and change its behaviour

Comment: is there any other tutorials that can explain to me more ? thanks

Comment: yes, or you can say that I don't have a complete code or a tutorial for it, can you provide me with it?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this post: http://techdroid.kbeanie.com/2010/04/custom-autocomplete-for-android.html
Hope that helps!